# Updating a single span value with multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, ajax, select

How can I update a single span value with the inputs of multiple select boxes, as in the following example:

```
 <html>
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#option1").change(onSelectChange);
                  $("#option2").change(onSelectChange);
          $("#option3").change(onSelectChange);
                  $("#option4").change(onSelectChange);
            });
            function onSelectChange(){

                  var Value1 = $("#option1").val();
                  var Value2 = $("#option2").val();
                  var Value3 = $("#option3").val();
                  var Value4 = $("#option4").val();
                  output =  Value1 + Value2 + Value3 + Value4;

                  $("#output").html(output);
            }
      </script>
</head>
<body>


      <select name="option1" id="option1">
            <option value="0">No Quarters</option>
            <option value=".25">1 Quarter</option>
            <option value=".50">2 Quarters</option>
            <option value=".75">3 Quarters</option>
      </select>

      <select name="option2" id="option2">
            <option value="0">No Dimes</option>
            <option value=".10">1 Dime</option>
            <option value=".20">2 Dimes</option>
      </select>

<select name="option3" id="option3">
        <option value="0">No Nickles</option>
        <option value=".05">1 Nickel</option>

</select>
<select name="option4" id="option4">
  <option value="0">No Pennies</option>
  <option value=".01">1 Penny</option>
  <option value=".02">2 Pennies</option>
  <option value=".03">3 Pennies</option>
  <option value=".04">4 Pennies</option>
</select>
<div>You have: $<span id="output">0</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is a user could input the number and types of coins in his pocket and see the total value of all the coins as he is updating them.  I can't seem to suss how to add the values of the selected options.

Thank you for helping a newbie!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works but you need to convert your input strings to floats. Change:

```
output =  Value1 + Value2 + Value3 + Value4;
```

to

```
output =  parseFloat(Value1) + parseFloat(Value2) + parseFloat(Value3) + parseFloat(Value4);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6BgL8/)**

Comment: Wondering why parseFloat throw NaN if used inside `.each` with `this.value`  http://jsfiddle.net/fb8gY/1/? +1 for correct and fast answer.

Comment: Why would you need each in that particular example? This would work: `$('select').change(function(){
     $("#output").html($(this).val());
});
`

Comment: To add value of all select elements. `parseFloat` works if we pass `$("someid").val()` as you did in your answer.So whats wrong if we pass `$(this).val()` ? Both are jQuery objects.

Comment: Just reallized `var output` should be `var output = 0`

Comment: Ya, realized that extra iteration is useless and I hate JS for its loosely coupled data types

Comment: I'm choosing this answer since it functions exactly as I need it to, it was thorough, and prompt.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
 $('select').change(function(){
   output += parseFloat(this.value);
   $("#output").html(output);
});
```

Better add some class and bind events to only required elements.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fb8gY/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert the "Value" strings to floats. Like so:

```
output =  parseFloat(Value1) + parseFloat(Value2) + parseFloat(Value3) + parseFloat(Value4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add some classes to your select's, you can simplify the code a ton: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6Br/

```
var totalValue = 0;

$(".money").change(function() {
    totalValue+=Number(this.value);
    $("#output").text(totalValue);
});
```

Comment: Selected answer, for simplification of code.  I appreciated all responses.  Very prompt, helpful, and descriptive: all.  Thanks for helping me scale the learning curve!

Comment: actually, this gives odd results when updating quantities.  Put in 1 quarter, 0 quarters, then 3 quarters: it says I have $1.

Answer (score 0):

You are just concatenating the strings rather than adding them as values. Hence, you just need to convert the value strings to floats for it to work.

So your

```
output =  Value1 + Value2 + Value3 + Value4;
```

would become

```
output =  parseFloat(Value1) + parseFloat(Value2) + parseFloat(Value3) + parseFloat(Value4);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `.val()` you are getting a string and when you `+` strings you do concatenation rather than addition. You need to convert your values to numbers:

```
              var Value1 = +$("#option1").val();              //unary + converts to a number
              var Value2 = +$("#option2").val();
              var Value3 = +$("#option3").val();
              var Value4 = +$("#option4").val();
              output =  Value1 + Value2 + Value3 + Value4;    //this is now addition
```

Comment: This is very informative.  I appreciate your help. Thank you!